# Impossible to connect to wifi with intel link 5100

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, intel

I have a GD6000 that uses Intel link 5100. I'm not able to connect to internet.  I'm new to ubuntu...`
Thanks for your help!

```
cat /etc/lsb-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"



lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M-E LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
0d:06.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
0d:06.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
0d:06.4 Communication controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 GemCore based SmartCard controller


lspci -nn | grep -i net

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f5] (rev 03)
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]


lspci -k

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M-E LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 408a
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
    Subsystem: Device 174c:2104
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0d:06.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 3009
    Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
0d:06.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 3009
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
0d:06.4 Communication controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 GemCore based SmartCard controller
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Device 3009

---------------

sudo lshw -C network

[sudo] password for pasy: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 19
       information bus: pci@0000:00:19.0
       nom logique: eth0
       version: 03
       numéro de série: 00:0a:e4:16:78:3a
       taille: 1Gbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=1.8-3 ip=192.168.1.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       ressources: irq:35 mémoire:f4700000-f471ffff mémoire:f4724000-f4724fff portE/S:1820(taille=32)
  *-network DÉSACTIVÉ
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: WiFi Link 5100
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:08:00.0
       nom logique: wlan0
       version: 00
       numéro de série: 00:22:fb:2d:8a:a4
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-31-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       ressources: irq:36 mémoire:f4500000-f4501fff

-------------

lsmod


Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0 
snd_hrtimer            16384  0 
bnep                   20480  2 
rfcomm                 69632  0 
bluetooth             491520  10 bnep,rfcomm
arc4                   16384  2 
iwldvm                237568  0 
mac80211              708608  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               188416  1 iwldvm
pcmcia                 65536  0 
snd_hda_codec_si3054    16384  1 
cfg80211              524288  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
mxm_wmi                16384  0 
acer_wmi               20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
snd_hda_intel          36864  3 
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
coretemp               16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm_intel             151552  0 
kvm                   479232  1 kvm_intel
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  3 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  4 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  3 snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    86016  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
i915                 1048576  3 
joydev                 20480  0 
serio_raw              16384  0 
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 i915
yenta_socket           45056  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            20480  1 yenta_socket
pcmcia_core            24576  3 pcmcia,pcmcia_rsrc,yenta_socket
lpc_ich                24576  0 
shpchp                 40960  0 
drm                   344064  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
wmi                    20480  2 acer_wmi,mxm_wmi
8250_fintek            16384  0 
video                  20480  2 i915,acer_wmi
tpm_infineon           20480  0 
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
psmouse               114688  0 
ahci                   36864  2 
firewire_ohci          40960  0 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
firewire_core          69632  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
e1000e                237568  0 
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp

-------------

iwconfig


eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.


-------------------

ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:e4:16:78:3a  
          inet adr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::20a:e4ff:fe16:783a/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:407036 erreurs:0 :7 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:234073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:569029743 (569.0 MB) Octets transmis:18776603 (18.7 MB)
          Interruption:17 Mémoire:f4700000-f4720000

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:9876 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9876 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          Octets reçus:811510 (811.5 KB) Octets transmis:811510 (811.5 KB)

------------

sudo iwlist scan

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

-----------

uname -r -m

3.19.0-31-generic x86_64

-------------

cat  /etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

-------------

nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:22:FB:2D:8A:A4

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points


- Device: eth0  [Connexion filaire 1] ------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:0A:E4:16:78:3A

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.1
68.1.110
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

---------------

sudo rfkill list


0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

`

Comment: Your wireless shows `Hard blocked:yes`. Please switch the wireless button or switch on your laptop.

Comment: Hi,  I don't understand, the wifi is switched on... I turn it off and on... nothing... thanks for your time!

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi` then do: `sudo rfkill unblock all` and finally: `rfkill list all` Is the hard block now no? If so, I will propose a solution.

Comment: Everything is now at "no"!  Thanks for your time!!!  It's working!!!  Thanks so much!

Comment: but... I have to enter those code every time I open the computer... Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper module `acer-wmi` is supposed to translate key presses into action, in your case, turn on the wireless. In a few cases, it is faulty and  must be removed in order for the wireless to function. Let's blacklist the module:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Wow!  Not sure I understand but...everything is now working perfectly.  Thanks a lot!!!